# why index keyword is return empty $_GET on seo url with htaccess in apache 2.4.18?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use wamp server 3.0.4

my htaccess code is here

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

but when i enter this `url = "localhost/myproject/index"`

my `$_GET` array is empty = `array()`

when i enter this `url = "localhost/myproject/second"`

my `$_GET` array is = `[_url] => /second/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to use `MultiViews` option turned on. Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/index` is the URL then Apache will serve matching `/index.php`.

Turn it off using this line at top of .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Also i would remove .htaccess and move this rewrite rules just to vhost config.